# Why does my ffmpeg command fails from python subprocess?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to concat two movies with ffmpeg. In the shell I can execute this:
`\\programs\2d\ffmpeg\inst\ffmpeg.bat -y -i "concat:C:/daten/movieA.ts1|C:/daten/movieB.ts2" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc C:/daten/movieConcat.mov` and it works fine. If I try to call it from a python subprocess:

```
import subprocess
cmd = [r"\\programs\2d\ffmpeg\inst\ffmpeg.bat", "-i", '"concat:C:/daten/movieA.ts1|C:/daten/movieB.ts2"', "-c", "copy", "-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc", "C:/daten/movieConcat.mov"]
result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
if result.returncode > 0:
    print("create concat failed")
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

I get this error:

```
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
[in#0 @ 00000222c056a1c0] Error opening input: Invalid argument
Error opening input file "concat:C:/daten/movieA.ts1|C:/daten/movieB.ts2".
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
```

I have no idea what's wrong with my call and I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: I think it might have to do with that you're using a pipe operator "|" in the cmd

Comment: I'm pretty sure the extra quotes around `"concat:C:/daten/movieA.ts1|C:/daten/movieB.ts2"` are your error, but Windows is crazy so maybe there's more.

Comment: The trailing option msg looks to be due to passing `"-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc"` as one token. The input open error looks to be inadequate escaping in the input URLs - escape the colon and possibly the pipe.

Comment: If I remove the quotes, I get an error: `C: is not recognized as internal or external command..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On Windows, if args is a sequence, it will be converted to a string in
> a manner described in [Converting an argument sequence to a string on
> Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence). This is because the underlying CreateProcess() operates on
> strings.

from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

You can try passing cmd as a single string with ' && ' between string commands

```
import subprocess
    
cmd = r'\\programs\2d\ffmpeg\inst\ffmpeg.bat -y -i "concat:C:/daten/movieA.ts1|C:/daten/movieB.ts2" && -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc C:/daten/movieConcat.mov'
    
   
result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
if result.returncode > 0:
    print("create concat failed")
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```